# Web server that runs on Android and comes with SQLite

Tags: android, web-server, sqlite

I would like the software to

- run on Android
- be a web server
- be able to execute PHP pages
- come with SQLite installed so that I can just load the files and sqlite db  into htdocs
- allow the user of the device on which it is installed to be able to access it through the browser

I do not need anything fancy like phpmyadmin, just enough to run a simple php file with an sqlite db, but if it has extra features then that's fine.

Comment: https://alternativeto.net/software/ulti-server-php-mysql-pma/ has MySql, rather than Sqlite